# Integrating CSS and CherryPy: How to fix the 404 "/" Not Found Error?

Tags: python, css, http-status-code-404, cherrypy

I've been working on testing Twitter Bootstrap with CherryPy 3.2.2, and have reviewed several of the SO posts, but have been unable to successfully get Cherry to run with my configuration files. I'm getting the infamous 404 error: "NotFound: (404, "The path '/' was not found.")".

This is my file setup:

- /TwitApp (application directory)

  - testPy.py (my test application)
  - config.conf (configuration file to add CSS)
  - global.conf (global configuration for server socket, port, etc. I think this can go in config.conf?)
  - /css (CSS folder)

    - bootstrap.min.css
  - /js (javascript directory)

This is my testPy.py code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    import cherrypy
    class HelloWorld:
          def index(self):
              return '''<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
                     <title>Bootstrap Test</title>
                     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                     <!-- Bootstrap -->
                     <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
                     </head><body>
                     <h1>Bootstrap Test</h1>
                     <button type="button" class="btn">Submit</button>
                     </body></html>'''
          index.exposed = True

    #I tried this example that I found in the documentation and on previous posts with the same 404 result:
    #cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld(), "/", "config.conf")

    #I tried this one when I reviewed another post on here:
    cherrypy.config.update("global.conf")
    cherrypy.tree.mount(HelloWorld(),"/","config.conf")
    cherrypy.engine.start()
    cherrypy.engine.block()
```

At one point the [global] section of my global.conf file was the top section of my config.conf file, but I split the two up when I started using the mount, start and block methods.

Here is my global.conf file:

```
    [global]
    server.socket_host = "127.0.0.1"
    server.socket_port = 8080
    log.screen: True
    log.error_file: "/Users/myUser/tmp/newproject/cherrypy.error"
    log.access_file: "/Users/myUser/tmp/newproject/cherrypy.access"
```

Here is my config.conf file:

```
    [/]
    tools.staticfile.root = "/Users/myUser/tmp/newproject/TwitApp"

    [/css/bootstrap.min.css]
    tools.staticfile.on = True
    tools.staticfile.filename = "css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

This is the full error message:
        404 Not Found

```
    The path '/' was not found.

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/CherryPy-3.2.2-py2.7.egg/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 656, in respond
        response.body = self.handler()
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/CherryPy-3.2.2-py2.7.egg/cherrypy/lib/encoding.py", line 188, in __call__
        self.body = self.oldhandler(*args, **kwargs)
       File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/CherryPy-3.2.2-py2.7.egg/cherrypy/_cperror.py", line 386, in __call__
        raise self
       NotFound: (404, "The path '/' was not found.")
```

The articles I read through the most can be found here: [Cherrypy returning NotFound: (404, "The path '/' was not found.")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9984378/cherrypy-returning-notfound-404-the-path-was-not-found) and here: [Path Not Found in CherryPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17120216/path-not-found-in-cherrypy). Can someone please advise what I'm doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final answer: I decided that I should just start troubleshooting, so I hacked down all of the CherryPy configurations and just did a basic `cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld())` with the template I had. I was still getting the 404 error, so that meant that there was something fundamentally wrong with my code, not a config error. I kept looking through everything and then I found it. On vim, my code alignment was a little off and that's when I noticed that `index.exposed = True` was not set outside the index function! D'oh! I replaced it and now it's working with CSS, so anyone who's interested in learning how to implement CherryPy with CSS, there ya go!

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at https://github.com/btsuhako/bootstrap-cherrypy-jinja2

In the configuration files, it's easier to setup a static dir in your CherryPy app config file:

```
[/css]
tools.staticdir.on: True
tools.staticdir.dir: 'css'

[/js]
tools.staticdir.on: True
tools.staticdir.dir: 'js'
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I was able to resolve the issue by opening the project in the editor that I originally used--vim--and fix the indenting so that cherrypy.expose wasn't part of the function block. I'm only using decorators now to avoid that problem (@cherrypy.expose). Staticfile was the first solution I came across so I used it and it worked, but I'll change it over to staticdir in my next iteration.